# How do I set a imageView to scale from the top right handcorner

Tags: android, image, background

I have an image that I want to use as a background for an activity.

I would like to take the screens height and width from the top right hand corner of the image. For example in the image below a screen the size of the red square would display that portion of the image, where as a blue screen would display everything in the blue square.

This is similar to a background image in html with the parameters 'cover' and 'top right corner fixed'.
[image]

Comment: Could you show some code? How are you implementing this image?

Comment: Ideally I would like to set the image in xml. Currently I have:

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="1900dp"
        android:layout_height="951dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerInParent="false"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/bgnd" />

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using android:layout_width="1900dip" and android:layout_height="951dip" and removing some of the extra but not really import attributes you have. Dip is a better solution than dp for image sizes across android devices(since their screen sizes are all different).

For the blue screen image have its height and width match the parent which would be the relative layout which will allow for it to fill the whole page. Then the red image will overlap from the top right.

```
<ImageView 
   android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
   android:layout_width="1900dip"
   android:layout_height="951dip"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
   android:src="@drawable/bgnd" 
/>
```

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately it does not work. I think this is due to the relative layout parent not allowing any children to extend beyond the edges of the screen.

Comment: I don't understand, is the blue box trying to extends beyond the screen?

Comment: No, the blue box is a screen of a certain size, in the same way the red box is a device of a different size.